# Including the bundler gem itself in my Rails app

Tags: ruby, deployment, configuration, rubygems, bundler

Bundler is great.  But there's one gem that it won't work for, and that's the `bundler` gem itself, which still needs to be installed manually:

```
Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with `gem install bundler`.
```

Besides being an extra step, this opens the door to version incompatibilities with Bundler itself.

Is there a way to include Bundler itself in my app, so that it relies on the included bundler gem?

Answer (score 0):

No. The ruby gems stay on the user environment, you can't distribute it with your project, the user need to install the bundler.
and Bundler can't bundle itself. :)

Comment: "Bundler can't bundle itself".  It wouldn't have to.  Include the bundle command in bin/ and it's requirements in the project dir, and there shouldn't be any need for the systm gem.  Just like, as odd as it is, a compiler can compile itself, there's nothing inherently stopping bundler from bundling itself.